# Magento 2.2.2 product image not updating

Tags: magento2, product-images

We have a magento 2.2.3 based website and a bunch of configurable products. Now we just tried to update the base image of the parent/configurable product we saved it and cleared cache and we see the new updated image in the admin panel however on the customer facing side the image still shows the original image. Even though we cleared browser cache and in magento reindexed and cleared cache.

suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

there,
You asked that question very long time ago, but still I found out the same issue today in newer version of Magento 2.

The Solution that worked for me:
When uploading new images for product does not set the roles (base, thumbnail and etc) first save it without any roles - flush the cache - then go back to the product and you may set the roles easily again.
The images are update without any issue.

I hope that this will help someone else looking for an solution.

Cheers,